# Using HTML And Web Languages For Windows Mobile Development

Tags: windows-mobile, air

I'm now thinking in develop some Windows Mobile applications in a different language, then I choosed HTML and the other Web Languages, but:

- It's possible to use Web languages to develop Windows Mobile applcations, as Adobe AIR in PCs?

  - Where can I get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are willing to wait a bit, Adobe is planning on releasing a version of Adobe Air that runs on Windows Mobile.

The nearest thing is Appceletor Titanium, but that runs on iPhone, and not Windows Mobile yet, although if memory serves correctly they also have ideas about that too.

I don't know about any other platforms, unless you intend to run them in a web browser like Opera or IE.

Comment: Thanks very much! I'm going to wait for the Adobe release very anxious.